# Using LOCATE with accents

Tags: mysql

How I can use LOCATE ignoring accents on comparison? For instance:

```
SELECT LOCATE('a', 'João'); -- Fail
>> Currently: 0
>> Need:      3

SELECT LOCATE('ã', 'João'); -- Ok
>> Currently: 3
>> Need:      3
```

How I can do that? I can't use LIKE on this case (and it works!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `latin1` charset, some accents will be ignored. This can have unexpected behaviour on some inputs however, so be sure to test thoroughly.

```
SET character_set_connection='latin1';
SELECT LOCATE('a', 'João');
```

Comment: Can I use with COLLATE method?

Comment: I don't believe there's a UTF-8 collation which will do what you want. And you can't use a latin1 collation on UTF-8 data without converting it.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you may want to reset the character set after running this query as it will take effect for the life of the connection.

Answer (score 3):

A good solution is that (based on Michael Mior answer):

```
  SELECT LOCATE('a', CONVERT('João' USING latin1));
```

Benchmarking (Michael Mior method):

```
  SET character_set_connection='latin1';
  SELECT LOCATE('a', 'João');
  >> 10.000.000 run at 0.532s
```

Benchmarking (current method):

```
  SELECT LOCATE('a', CONVERT('João' USING latin1));    
  >> 10.000.000 run at 1.906s
```

Michael Mior version is 4 times faster.